# Fancy container - Fancy box

Tags: tikz-pgf, fancyhdr, draw, fancybox

Please, I would like to know how can I produce this type of fancy container in latex. Do I have to use fancy box or something like that?

Thanks in advance for any help

[image: Fancy container]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) On this site, a question should typically revolve around an abstract issue (e.g. "How do I get a double horizontal line in a table?") rather than a concrete application (e.g. "How do I make this table?"). Questions that look like "Please do this complicated thing for me" tend to get closed because they are either "off topic", "too broad", or "unclear". Please try to make your question clear and simple by giving a [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228): you'll stand a greater chance of getting help.

Comment: This is from `bclogo` package in conjunction with `tcolorbox`, most likely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `bclogo` package and its `bclogo` environment, changing the default logo with `logo=\bccrayon`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[tikz]{bclogo}

\begin{document}

\begin{bclogo}[logo={\bccrayon},arrondi=0.1]{Code}
\blindtext
\end{bclogo}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @AmarMouhamadou: Happy TeXing then!